# You are using download over http. Currently Unity adds NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to Info.plist to simplify transition

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, https

making an app for both iOS and Android with Unity.

I'm now stuck on an iOS problem:

```
You are using download over http. Currently unity adds `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `Info.plist` to simplify transition, but it will be removed soon. Please consider updating to https.
```

unsupported URL

The actual problem is:
- `I connect to an https address`
- `I did set the Allow Arbitrary Loads to YES`

Yet, it's not working.

Here's my code:

```
string GET = "mail="+mail+"&nome="+nome+"&cognome="+cognome;
// get parameters
WWW response = new WWW (SERVER+"adduser/?"+GET);
// calling page, address is like 'https://website.com/'
while (!response.isDone && response.error != "") {
    yield return null;
}
if (response.error != "") {
    print (response.error);
    return false;
}
```

obviously, this is in a `IEnumerator` function and it ALWAYS returns the previous error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple stopped allowing *http* connections on iOS devices. You can still use *http* connection by adding `NSAppTransportSecurity` to the  `info.plist` but this will be removed in the future.It is recommended that you use https connection from now.

- http://yourdomain.com will give you this error.
- https://yourdomain.com will **NOT** give you this error and is what Apple
  recommends now.

[`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html) was introduced to automatically solve this problem by adding `NSAppTransportSecurity` to the  `info.plist`.

```
IEnumerator makeRequest()
{
    string GET = "mail=" + mail + "&nome=" + nome + "&cognome=" + cognome;
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(SERVER + "adduser/?" + GET);
    yield return www.Send();

    if (www.isError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error while downloading: " + www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        // Show results as text
        Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);

        // Or retrieve results as binary data
        byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
    }
}
```

---

Note that your app may be rejected if you add `NSAppTransportSecurity` to the  `info.plist` without good explanation to Apple. Again, it is recommended that you upgrade your server and use *https* instead of *http*.

Comment: I'm sorry, i thought i did accept the answer, then i don't know why i did un-acccept, i'm actually still trying to understand how SO works

Comment: @Programmer I used UnityWebRequest and www.SendWebrequest() but its still showing the same message

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55980413/any-permanent-solution-this-error-download-over-http-please-consider-updating ...Look here