# Any permanent solution this error "Download over http ,please consider updating to https" in Unity?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

Trying to upload two different files into backend server.One is .json file and other is .worldmap file.When I upload I get this error in the debug "**You are using download over http. Currently Unity adds NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to Info.plist to simplify transition, but it will be removed soon. Please consider updating to https.
Generic/unknown HTTP error**" 
I have noticed that sometimes this error shows up and sometimes not.From this [Link solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39296567/you-are-using-download-over-http-currently-unity-adds-nsallowsarbitraryloads-to) the solution is to add UnityWebRequest.I have used that but still it continues to show up.Anything to do with my code ,webaddress or too many http calls from my code?

```
public void UploadMaps()
{

   StartCoroutine(UploadFileData());
   StartCoroutine(UploadWorldMap());

}
IEnumerator UploadFileData()

{
    string mapnamedl = "pathtest";
    Debug.Log("Mapname local = " + mapnamedl);
    string locapath ="file://" +Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + mapnamedl + ".json";
    Debug.Log("local path = " + locapath);
    WWW localFile = new WWW(locapath);
    yield return localFile;

    if(localFile.error==null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Local file found successfully");

    }

    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Open file error: " + localFile.error);
        yield break; // stop the coroutine here
    }



    Debug.Log("Form bytes = " + BitConverter.ToString(localFile.bytes));




    List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
   formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("Jsondata",localFile.bytes));

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://testsite.com/cab/test/save.php",formData);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        string JSONDATAstring = www.downloadHandler.text;
        Debug.Log("Json String is = " + JSONDATAstring);
        JSONNode JNode = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(JSONDATAstring);

        string login = (JNode["upload"][0]["success"]).ToString();

        Debug.Log("login is = " + login);

        if (login == "1")
        {

            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");

        }
        else if (login == "0")
        {

            Debug.Log("Failed ");

        }


    }
}


IEnumerator UploadWorldMap()
// IEnumerator UploadFileData(string mapnamedl)
{
    string mapnamedl = "pathtest";
    Debug.Log("Mapname local = " + mapnamedl);
    string locapath = "file://" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + mapnamedl + ".worldmap";
    Debug.Log("local path = " + locapath);
    WWW localFile = new WWW(locapath);
    yield return localFile;

    if (localFile.error == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Local file found successfully");

    }

    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Open file error: " + localFile.error);
        yield break; // stop the coroutine here
    }



    Debug.Log("Form bytes = " + BitConverter.ToString(localFile.bytes));




    List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
    formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("Jsondata", localFile.bytes));

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://testsite.com/cab/test/save.php", formData);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        string JSONDATAstring = www.downloadHandler.text;
        Debug.Log("Worldmap String is = " + JSONDATAstring);
        JSONNode JNode = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(JSONDATAstring);

        string login = (JNode["upload"][0]["success"]).ToString();

        Debug.Log("Worldmap login is = " + login);

        if (login == "1")
        {

            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");

        }
        else if (login == "0")
        {

            Debug.Log("Failed ");

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the HTTP protocol (the `http://` at the beginning of your URL). Apple enforces all kinds of random policies, one of which is that you must communicate over HTTPS, the secure version of HTTP. Try changing your URLs to https. If the server you're connecting to supports them, great. Otherwise, you'll need to make the server https-friendly by getting an HTTPS certificate and installing it on your server (if it's yours; otherwise, you're out of luck).

Comment: It was working till morning and suddenly it stopped working.why is that?

Comment: That may have something to do with the "Generic/unknown HTTP error" part. Is the server available?

Comment: Generic/unknown HTTP error
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)<UploadFileData> but server got  no problems

Comment: I asked the backend team to change to https...They changed it but still the problem is there..